# Is there a way to reflect 'filament color change' in Cura-generated thumbnails?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, octoprint, color

I'm using the OctoPrint plugin [Cura Thumbnails](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/UltimakerFormatPackage/) along with the **Filament Change** post-processing plugin in Cura 5.5:

[image: Screenshot of Cura's Post-Processing plugins]

I want to create multi-color thumbnails that keep into account the 'Filament Change' script that was used, for example, when printing something as shown below:

[image: Photo of two multi-colored 3D printed pyramids]

Can the use of the **Filament Change** script in the Create Thumbnail script be reflected so that the **Create Thumbnail** script can account for the color change with the desired colors, and the thumbnail will contain multiple colors, as shown in the above image?

For reference: [OctoPrint-UltimakerFormatPackage: Feature Request](https://github.com/jneilliii/OctoPrint-UltimakerFormatPackage/issues/64) and [Ultimaker/Cura: Feature Request](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/17459).